# Appendind return of a function results in None

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have a function that returns a list:

```py
def get_all_newids() -> list:
    return list(group_dict.values())
```

When I'm trying to append this list on assignment it assigns `None`:

```py
grpids = get_all_newids().append('42')  # None
```

If I append after the assignment everything works as expected:

```py
grpids = get_all_newids()
grpids.append('42')  #  ['33', '42']
```

Just wondering why exactly this is happening. And is there any way to do this in one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eumiro provided a solution, however this was left unanswered:

> Just wondering why exactly this is happening.

Because it's idiomatic (though not universal) for "mutating" methods to return `None` in Python when there is not a very good reason for them to return something (e.g. `pop` would be much less useful if it did not return the value it pops).

`append` adds an item to a list, and returns nothing because there is no return value intrinsic to appending. Likewise `extend`, `insert`, `remove`, `reverse` or `sort`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line:

```
grpids = get_all_newids() + ['42']
```